# Create an Artificial Callback function to enable Callbacks to .addclass and .css in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-callback

I have used the slideUp/Down functions in Jquery to animate a div on my page, but it runs poorly on iPhones, so I decided to write a Webkit equivalent to solve the performance problem, but you cannot apply a callback to the jQuery .css, or .addclass.

I have this function:

```
$('#collapse').css('height','0');
```

But I need to fake a callback essentially make this work:

```
$('#collapse').css('height','0', function() {
//do something after
});
```

Anyone know how to do this?

The Webkit animation is set to 1 sec.

Comment: Why don't you use the .animate() function? http://api.jquery.com/animate/ you can use his callback handler to do anything after the animation has been completed

Comment: @VAShhh `slideUp` and `slideDown` use `animate` internally, so I see no reason to think they won't have the same performance problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `setTimeout`; jQuery has no way of telling whether an inbuilt browser animation has completed:

```
$('#collapse').css('height', 0);
setTimeout(function() {
    // code will happen after the timeout has completed
}, 1000); // 1 second
```

The downside of this is that you have to set the time for the animation in two places.

Comment: Another possibility: http://syropia.net/journal/css3-transition-callbacks-in-jquery

Comment: @RenanFranca What a difference four years makes! Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibilite is syropia.net/journal/css3-transition-callbacks-in-jquery

=D